# How to get Intel HAXM working on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v, haxm

When installing the IntelHaxm-Android package I get the following error despite Hyper-V being disabled:
[image: Install dialog error]

From the image it is visible that hyper-v is disabled. Processor is Intel i7-6700 that definitely supports VT-x, and virtualization is enabled in BIOS.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V prevents running HAXM on your computer. You have two choices:

## Remove Hyper-V

#### (if you don't use Hyper-V at all)

1. Open PowerShell window as Administrator and execute command:

   ```
   Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
   ```
2. Restart computer and voila - you can use HAXM or VirtualBox.

## Create alternative Windows 10 configuration with Hyper-V disabled

#### (if you have to use Hyper-V for another purpose)

1. Open command line as Administrator.
2. Clone existing configuration (with Hyper-V installed and enabled) and give  it meaningful description:

   ```
   BCDEDIT /copy {current} /d "Hyper-V enabled"
   ```
3. Disable Hyper-V in current configuration:

   ```
   BCDEDIT /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```
4. Rename current configuration:

   ```
   BCDEDIT /set {current} description "Hyper-V disabled"
   ```
5. Restart computer and select configuration with Hyper-V disabled to run HAXM.

Comment: Hi @Wojciech, I will try it and let you know if this worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that was resolved by [this answer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/537144#comment-1846715) from a forum

> this is what i did to install haxm 1.1.4 on win 8.1 Pro 64-bit. you
>   may test it with or without admin-privileges, i've done it with them
>   :-| (this means to start cmd and any other exe in admin mode)
>
> I. Preparing---------------------------------------------------------
>   (Optional: check or change your BIOS settings for Intel VT, disable
>   hyper-v, ... as mentioned in other answers.)
>
> 1. download and extract the file to a folder
> 2. cmd -> sfc /SCANNOW
> 3. reboot
> 4. cmd -> Bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
> 5. reboot
>
> II. Installation-----------------------------------------------------
>   1. start install-android.exe in the folder of the extracted file and install
>   1.1 if you don't get an error the previous steps have handled the error - continue to III.
>   1.2 if you get an error DO NOT click OK when the error occurs
>   3. go to C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM and copy all files, except *.tmp to a new folder
>   4. then continue/finish the setup (click OK and finish)
>   5. copy the files from the new folder to C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM and delete *.tmp
>   6. go to C:\Program Files\Intel\HAXM, right-click on the inf-file and choose install a window with driverinstallation should appear. install
>   driver. it should says ok then..
>
> hint: this is what made the difference for me! Starting "HaxInst64.exe
>   /i intelhaxm.inf 1" as well as with parameter 4 in the console did not
>   pop up the driverinstallation-window
>
> III. Test------------------------------------------------------------
>   1. cmd -> sc query intelhaxm it should show the service
>   2. reboot
>   3. cmd -> sc query intelhaxm it should says service running..
>
> IV. Reset------------------------------------------------------------
>   1. cmd -> Bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING OFF
>   2. reboot

Comment: Tnx Oleg, I will try

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me, I am now exploring how to make use of hyper-v as I need it also now active on this machine.
With this no luck so far.